# Servlet to REST WebService

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets

I have a servlet which accepts two input parameters using doGet method and do some processing.
How can I make servlet to a RESTful webservice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You really don't seem to know what a RESTful web service is. I suggest you research the subject a little bit before proceeding.

Comment: Do a little bit of research before asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already a REST service. Most REST service Java libraries are based on servlets. Now it depends on your "mapping" of your "resources":

Servlets mostly process this kind of requests with query parameters:

```
http://host:port/context/endPoint?a=100%b=test
```

This is considered a "correct" REST resource end point:

```
http://host:port/context/endPoint/100/test
```